# Determine if my Galaxy is 8 GB or 16 GB

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, internal-storage

I just got my Galaxy from eBay.
The auction said it's 16GB, but I am afraid I was a fraud victim; I'm checking at Settings->SD card and device storage->USB storage, and Total memory says 5.01GB.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My Galaxy S Vibrant has 16 GB internal SD storage, and `Settings -> SD card and phone storage` reports 12.78 GB.  I would assume the ~3 GB difference is due to the reported size being actually in [GiB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibibyte), not GB, and partitioning (the internal data partition is 1.84 GiB as reported by [Titanium Backup](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup)) and formatting.  The numbers work out, anyways.

Given that 8 - 5.01 is also ~3, I would say that you have an 8 GB model on your hands.  Checking with Titanium (requires root) or something else might be a good idea.

Comment: @Shimmy It's certainly hard to say.  One way that makes some sense is to scale it by the difference in price of the models as sold new, $239 vs $199.  183.50 - ((183.50 / 239) * 199) = $30.71.  That amount might be an appropriate refund.  Of course you might not want the 8 GB model at all ... I really think the seller should have to pay for return shipping in these cases, but I don't make the laws :P